# Помощь с циклами

Tags: c#

Задание: Друзья составили про Петю задачу: наш друг Петя ест невкусную макаронину длиной 60км. Каждый день он съедает N метров этой макаронины (случайное число от  50 до 500). Сколько дней понадобится Пете, чтобы съесть всю макаронину? Сколько метров этой макаронины осталось Пете на последний день? Показать таблицу ежедневных Петиных достижений.

Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int m = 6000;
        Random rhd = new Random();
        int n;
        int d=0; 
        while (m > 0)
        {
            d++;
            n = rhd.Next(50, 500); //сколько в день съедает
            m = m - n; //остаток
            listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,3} день. Съедено {1,3} м. Осталось {2,5} м.", d,n,m));
        }
```

Как он работает: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка заключается в том, что Петя уходит в минус, мне нужно это как-то предотвратить. Может кто-нибудь подскажет как это сделать?

Comment: `n = Math.Min(m, rhd.Next(50, 500));`

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо

Answer (score 1):

надо проверять на отрицательные значения и всучали если вы выходите в минус корректировать его. и 60км = 60000м а не 6000м

Вариант 1
`n = Math.Min(m, rhd.Next(50, 500)) от пользователя` @tym32167

Вариант 2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _distance = 60000;

        int _todayEated = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int days = 0;
        while (_distance>0)
        {
            _todayEated = rnd.Next(50, 500);

            if (_distance - _todayEated < 0)
            {
                var synceat = _distance - _todayEated;
                _todayEated= _todayEated + synceat;
                _distance = _distance - _todayEated;
            }
            else
            {
                _distance = _distance - _todayEated;
            }


            days++;
            string result = string.Format("{0} день. Сьедено {1} M. Осталось {2} М.", days, _todayEated, _distance);
            listBox1.Items.Add(result);


        }


    }
```

Comment: вы предлагаете выбирать случайное число и потом его вручную уменьшать. По сути вы делаете то же самое, что делает вот эта строчка `n = Math.Min(m, rhd.Next(50, 500));`

Comment: Разные подходы одну и туже задачу можно реализовать разными способами

Comment: я согласен с вами. Но в то же время, если можно раписать код проще и понятней, то лучше это сделать. Я вам просто подсказываю, что одна строчка и одна операция будет проще для понимания, чем 5 строчек и 5 операций.

Comment: абсолютно с вами согласен когда писал ответ комментария не видел

Comment: В общем, если захотите улучшить свой ответ, не стесняйтесь использовать мой комментарий для этого.